# Does Explorer's "virtual filesystem" have public API?

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, explorer

Windows Explorer presents a virtual "filesystem", whose root is the Desktop folder, containing Recycle Bin and This/My Computer, which in turn contains mounted filesystems, Libraries, UPnP/MTP/PTP devices and Network Shortcuts.

[image: Explorer]

Given that the same layout can be observed in the builtin open/save/directory picker dialogs, one can assume that there's an (internal?) API exposing this "VFS".

Is this the case? If yes, is such API public and can it be used from my own applications?

Comment: It's called [the Shell Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144090(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given that the same layout can be observed in the builtin open/save/directory picker dialogs, one can assume that there's an (internal?) API exposing this "VFS".

Actually, the pickers displays a real Explorer window embedded within their UI and let Explorer handle the file system.

But yes, there is a public API, as @JonathanPotter mentioned - the [Shell Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144090.aspx).  This is the same API that Explorer itself uses for just about everything it does.

Folders and files are represented as [ITEMIDLIST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773321.aspx) identifers, and can be accessed using the [`IShellFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775075.aspx) and [`IShellItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144.aspx) interfaces (amongst others).

Start with [`SHGetDesktopFolder()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762175.aspx) to get the `IShellFolder` interface for the root Desktop folder, and then you can drill down through its hierarchy as needed, using [`IShellFolder::EnumObjects()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775066.aspx) to enumerate child folders/files, [`IShellFolde::BindToObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775059.aspx) to get `IShellFolder` interfaces for subfolders, [`IShellFolder::GetDisplayNameOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775071.aspx) to get folder/file names, etc.

There is a LOT that you can access/do with the Shell interfaces, this is not even scratching the surface of everything that is available.